# how lowering tdp decreases amount of heat produced?

Tags: power-supply, power, cooling

If there are two identical processors (ex 11 th gen 1165g7) with a single difference in its TDP value (eg. `base@1.6Ghz & tdp@18watt` and `base@2.8Ghz & tdp@28watt`) where turbo boost is 4.7ghz for both, then both processor at idle condition generate same heat and power consumption.

When load increases both processor has to increase their frequency (suppose a task needs processor constant speed of 2.3ghz for longer duration).

Then the processor `base@1.6` will use intel speedstep and turbo boost to do the work and it will take some power. Whereas the `base@2.8` will do under its base clock.

So to do same amount of work they need same amount of power if there is turbo boost facality. And if there is no workload the power consumption by both of them is less(or equal).

Then how can lowering TDP decreases amount of heat produced?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power) first and clarify your question if it's still not clear.

> The thermal design power (TDP), sometimes called thermal design point, is the **maximum amount of heat** generated by a computer chip or component (often a CPU, GPU or system on a chip) that **the cooling system in a computer is designed to dissipate under any workload**.

Different chips have different TDP because each of them was designed for different task/application.

TDP is affected by a multitude of factors such as the number of transistors and its density on silicon, thermal conductivity of its casing, operating voltage and designed frequency of its cores, etc.

Yet that doesn't say too much about the emitted heat under certain load (as in your question).

The real heat emitted by the chip is actually proportional to the energy consumed by changing transistors from 0 to 1 and back. When there is no switching, only little power is consumed and thus only little heat generated. (very simplified)

UPDATE: You don't seem to understand the difference between the maximum **designed** amount of heat that possibly can be transferred away from the chip (with its designed cooling) and its **momentary** power consumption and/or losses in form of heat, and mixing marketing tradenames in such as turboboost (simplified: short-term automatic overclocking) and speedstep (simplified: frequency+voltage controller with thermal feedback built into a CPU as well as inserting NOP cycles to allow for a cooldown).
There is only little those have in common.

You are asking why two vehicles (i.e. a personal car and a bus) produce different amount of exhaust gases under similar load, while TDP in this case would be their exhaust pipe diameter.
The results might be very close or very different. The link between those is very weak and YMMV.
Certainly a larger diameter **can** let more fumes out if needed and there was probably a reason to design it to that size. But that's it.

Comment: Turbo boost is 4.7ghz for both processor. If we assign a task of 3ghz, then both processor has to increase their frequency. When no work both processor frequency will be least. So both are doing same amount of work. So how heat production differs??